# Copy from table to another table without specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

In sql I have one blank table and second one with values

In me second one I have column with values like

```
poland-data
russia-data
usa-data
england-data
poland-data-hr
england-data-hr
england-hr
poland-hr
```

I want to copy to the blank table column with values without 'hr' from table nr.2
for example i only want to see in that table

```
poland-data
russia-data
usa-data
england-data
```

Comment: Does this need to be automated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

```
SELECT distinct REPLACE(col1 ,'-hr', '') as col1
INTO TableTwo 
FROM TableOne
```

Comment: `dbo`... in MySQL... really?

Comment: And what about them duplicates

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Is this a specific case of something that will have to be done many times with variable columns? If not, you should be able to just to

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 AS 
    SELECT poland_data,
           russia_data,
           usa_data,
           england_data
      FROM TABLE_1;
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
    SELECT poland_data,
           russia_data,
           usa_data,
           england_data
      FROM TABLE_1;
```

If you already have the table created.

Comment: I dont think this is a Create table requirement if you look carefully at the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I added the insert in case the table was already created

Comment: poland-data
russia-data
usa-data
england-data
poland-data-hr
england-data-hr
england-hr
poland-hr  this is everything in one column, and i want to copy and put that column in second table without  'hr' rows in names

Comment: @Hw3zs Please provide sample data and your expected result. "poland-data russia-data usa-data england-data poland-data-hr england-data-hr england-hr poland-hr is everything in one column" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: insert into table 2 select column_countries where column_countries not like '%hr' will be fine ?

Comment: @Hw3zs Okay, I think I see. These are values in a country column. Alright. In that case yeah, just insert with that like condition.